# How to define a relation N:N in python3+django2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, many-to-many

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/

In this tutorial, I can create a class `Question` and a class `Choice`. One question contains multiple choices, but one choice belongs to only 1 question.

So following the tutorial, there is a `foreign_key` in the class `Choice` that refers to the class `Question`, and the variable `choice_set` will be automatically created.

Now I want to modify that a choice can belong to multiple questions as well. How should I do that?

Comment: See [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

you will use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Please read yourself through the docs and play around with it to learn :)